# Returning all values with certain criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula, array-formulas

I need help with creating excel formula. I have a list of names in row 1 and list of values in row 2. I need a formula that would return all of the names from row 1 that has a certain value (lets call it "value1") in row 2. I know how to do that with VBA but I would rather avoid using macros if possible. I'm pretty sure it would be possible with array formulas but I'm not really good with it so I would appreciate a help.

Comment: return them how?  In one cell delineated with a comma, or something else, or in different cells as a list?

Comment: I was thinking about a list in different cells but I could work with it if it was in one cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($1:$1,AGGREGATE(15,6,COLUMN($A$2:$D$2)/($A$2:$D$2="X"),ROW(1:1))),"")
```

[image]

As it is copied down the selection will change.